# img:first-child not working for my first image

Tags: html, css, image

I've tried `#logos img:first-child{}` to try and format my top img a little different from the rest but it just doesn't work. Can anyone help me figure out why?

```html
<div id="logos" name="logos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <br>
            <h1 class="centered">SHOWS</h1>
            <img src="img/kenshows400x300.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Ken Cooper" width="400px" height="300px">
            <hr>
        </div><!-- end row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img src="img/shows/jkllogo450x300.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Jimmy Kimmel Live" width="450px" height="300px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img src="img/shows/latelateshowlogo450x300.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Late Late Show" width="450px" height="300px">
            </div>
        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `first-child` pseudo-selector selects any element which is the *first* child of its parent. In your example, in the first `.row` div, the `h1` "SHOWS" is the first element and your `img` is the second element. So it doesn't get selected. In contrast, in the other div, both `img` tags are the first child of their parent, so they *do* get selected.

In other words, `img:first-child` doesn't select the first `img` tag, it selects the `img` tag which is the first child of its parent. If it has a previous sibling, then `first-child` doesn't apply.

We can fix your code by instead putting the `first-child` on `.row` so that the img in the first row div is selected, which also happens to be the first image.

```css
#logos .row:first-child img {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="logos" name="logos">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <br>
     <h1 class="centered">SHOWS</h1>

     <img src="img/kenshows400x300.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Ken Cooper" width="400px" height="300px">

     <hr>
    </div> <!-- end row -->

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img src="img/shows/jkllogo450x300.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Jimmy Kimmel Live" width="450px"       height="300px">
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img src="img/shows/latelateshowlogo450x300.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Late Late Show" width="450px" height="300px">
     </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->

   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great. I used the css you provided for my one image on top and I used the #logos img:first-child{} for every other image. Without your explanation I wouldn't have figured that out so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`:first-child / :last-child` required any list in one section, but in your code `img` wrapped with div so try to add `:first-child` on just parent div, see below sample code

```
 #logos .row:first-child img{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
#logos .row:first-child img{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be first-of-type
try #logos img:first-of-type{}

Comment: No, `first-of-type` will match all three images.

Comment: i suppose this will work #logos .container .row:first-child img{}